# Law of Total Probability and Variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Assume that $X$ is a discrete random variable with support $\left\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}  \right\}$. Consider
 $\Pr \left[ f \left( X \right) <z \right] $. According to the Law of Total Probability, $\Pr \left[ f \left( X \right) <z \right]=E\left[ \Pr \left[f\left( X \right) <z|X \right] \right]=
\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \Pr \left[ 
f\left( X \right) <z|X=x_{i} \right] \Pr\left[X=x_{i} \right].$

The question is the following: can we plug $x_i$ directly into $f(X)$, to get 
$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \Pr \left[ 
f\left( x_i \right) <z|X=x_{i} \right] \Pr\left[X=x_{i} \right]$?

If the function $f(X)=X$ then the equations above work just fine. However, if $f(X)=var(X)$ then we end up with nonsense. Indeed, $\Pr \left[ var \left( X \right) <z \right]=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \Pr \left[ 
var\left( X \right) <z|X=x_{i} \right] \cdot \Pr\left[X=x_{i} \right]=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \Pr \left[ 
var\left( x_{i}  \right) <z|X=x_{i} \right] \cdot  \Pr\left[X=x_{i} \right] =\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \Pr \left[ 
0 <z|X=x_{i} \right] \cdot \Pr\left[X=x_{i} \right]=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} 1 \cdot  \Pr\left[X=x_{i} \right]=1, $ if $z \geq 0$ or, $=0,$ if $ z <0$

So why the Law of Total Probability ( or its version) does not work in the case of variance?

Comment: Cannot follow all of the last step. Since $Var[X]$ is a constant, $\Pr\{Var[X] < z\}$ is either $1$ or $0$. And when you apply the Law of Total Probability on this, it stills holds, so we will not end up with nonsense.

Comment: The $\Pr(Var(X)<z)=1$ if $Var(X) <z$, but by applying the LTP we have this probability equal 1 when $z \geq 0$. Does it make sense?

Comment: If $Var[X] < z$, then $\Pr\{Var[X] < z\} = 1$ and $\Pr\{Var[X] < z|X = x_i\} = \Pr\{Var[X] < z\} = 1$ so they are the same. The key is $\Pr\{Var[X] < z|X = x_i\} = \Pr\{Var[X] < z\}$ so it guarantee the result make sense. I am not sure how you obtain your claimed result.

Comment: If $Var(X)=2$ and $z=1$ then $\Pr(Var(X)<z)=\Pr(2<1)=0$, but if we apply LTP then we get $\Pr(Var(X)<z)=1$ since $z>0$, to see it just follow the derivation with LPT (as in the question). Does it make sense?

Comment: As said, the key is $\Pr\{Var[X]<z|X=x_i\}=\Pr\{Var[X]<z\}$ and $\Pr\{Var[X]<z|X=x_i\} \neq \Pr\{0 < z\}$ in general. The event has a probability of either $1$ or $0$ and thus independent to any other event, including itself. If you plug in the above example, $\Pr\{2 < 1\} = 0$, and $\Pr\{2 < 1| \text{anything}\} = 0$.

Comment: Not clear, why do you  keep saying that $\Pr\{Var[X]<z|X=x_i\}=\Pr\{Var[X]<z\}$, we have, instead, $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\Pr\{Var[X]<z|X=x_i\}\cdot \Pr\{X=x_i\}=\Pr\{Var[X]<z\}$

Comment: I guess, I see what you mean. The way I did it,  is replacing $X$ with $x_i$ in the $Var()$ , i.e. from $Var(X)$ get $Var(x_i)$ when conditioning on $X=x_i$, but you keep $Var(X)$ unchanged regardless of the condition $X=x_i$. My initial claim was that sometimes such a change is possible, i.e. when $f(X)$ is just $X$, please, see the question as posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in saying that on the event $\{X=x_i\}$ we have $\text{Var}(X)=\text{Var}(x_i)$. That is not the case. $\text{Var}(X)$ is simply a constant.

A random variable $X$ can be described as a function. Here, perhaps $X$ is a function from $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ with $X(i)=x_i$. This is a *deterministic* function, but we think about the input as being random. So the probability that $X$ takes on the value $x_i$ is the probability that $i$ is the input to the function $X$.

Now when we write $f(X)$ this is really a composition of functions. I.e., on input $i$ we have $f(X)=f\circ X(i)=f(x_i)$. So $f(X)$ is itself a random variable, that is, another function with domain $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. When we apply $f$ to the random variable $X$ we get out another random variable $f(X)$. Keep in mind that this $f$ must have domain containing the range of the random variable $X$ (in this case, $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$).

However, when we write $\text{Var}(X)$, this is not a composition of functions. There is not input to $\text{Var}(X)$. Rather, $\text{Var}$ is a function from the set of random variables (with finite second moment) to $\mathbb{R}$. So $\text{Var}$ takes in a random variable $X$ and spits out a *number* $\text{Var}(X)$. Notice that $\text{Var}$'s domain does *not* contain the range of $X$, since $\text{Var}$ takes in random variables, not numbers. So we cannot say $f=\text{Var}$ and apply the formula you derived for $f$.

The reason this may be confusing is because we don't like to write random variables as functions, since it's easier to just think of them as numbers that take on random values. Hence the notation gets overload, so that $f(X)$ denotes a random variable while $\text{Var}(X)$ denotes a number.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I cannot buy it. A number, which is a constant in this case, is also a random variable, though a specific one. Please, look at the definition of a random variable and try to see that a constant fits it pretty well.

Comment: Also, a random variable is not a function (or map) from numbers, like 1,2,3 etc, but a map from elements of a sample space to numbers, so your writing that "Here, perhaps X is a function from $\{1,2,3...,n\}$ " seems to be not accurate.

Comment: Actually, you'll see in the very first paragraph on the [random variable wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) that formally a random variable is a "measurable function." And you are correct that a constant is also a random variable. In any case, the important distinction is that $f$ is a function that takes in numbers and spits out numbers, while $\text{Var}$ is a function that takes in **random variables** and spits out numbers. Thus $f(X)$ is a random variable, while $\text{Var}(X)$ is a number.

Comment: If we take an expectation instead of variance then the formula seems to work all right, though expectation takes in a random variable and "spits out" a number.....

Comment: Also, we can consider $var(X)$ as a function from $R^n$ to R.

Comment: @Bob No, it doesn't work if $f=\mathbb{E}$. $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}[Z]<z)$ is either $0$ or $1$ depending on the value of $\mathbb{E}[Z]$. However, your formula returns $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(x_i<z)\mathbb{P}(X=x_i) = \sum_{i: x_i<z} \mathbb{P}(X=x_i)$ which will be between $0$ and $1$ if there are some $x_i<z$ and some $x_i \geq z$.

Comment: How exactly do you view $\text{Var}$ as a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$? It depends not only on the $x_i$'s but also on the values $\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)$. What do you mean by $\text{Var}(X)$ if $\text{Var}$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ while $X$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable?

Comment: Re the $Var$ as a function, we just take here $\Pr[X=x_i]$ as either parameters of the function or the parts of the function by itself. In other words, the $Var(X)$ is a composite function that depends on  $x_i$ directly and via probabilities, i.e. $\Pr[X=x_i]$.

Comment: Re the probability of expectation example - it is very interesting, thanks for point it out!